# Delegate not Working on Cloned Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delegates

I'm having trouble with a strange problem using delegate in jquery.

HTML:

```
<div id="workbenches">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="workbench">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
            <div> <! .workbench -->
        </div> <!-- .item -->
    </div> <!-- .carousel-inner -->
</div> <!-- #workbenches -->
```

Javascript:

In the following javascript, I cloned the div.item object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var workbenchObject = $('.carousel-inner .item');
        workbenchObject.clone().prependTo('#workbenches .carousel-inner').removeClass('active');
        workbenchObject.clone().appendTo('#workbenches .carousel-inner').removeClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Since some tags is generated by javascript, so I tried to bind the click event to the `a` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.workbench').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
</script>
```

However, the code above only works on the original `a` tag (, not works on the cloned objects).

What wrong with the code? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need bind the handler to `#workbenches`(or `#workbenches .carousel-inner`) because the `.workbench` object is created dynamically. Even in event delegation to handler should be added to a static element.

```
$('#workbenches').delegate('.workbench a', 'click', function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```